# Executing a terminal command in a java progam

Tags: java, runtime.exec, javap

```
javap -classpath /Users/amol/Documents/Java/ -l -c a
```

When I execute the above command in my terminal the output shows the function names in my class along with the local variables

```
Process process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
          "javap","-classpath","/Users/amol/Documents/Java/","-l","-c","a"});
```

However when I type the above line in netbeans and run it, it only show the function names and line numbers where the local variables have been declared.

Why is there a change in the output for the same command?

Comment: See the Java World article linked in [the info. page for runtime.exec](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  Follow the recommendations.

Comment: They do seem to be different commands, the 2nd has `-l -c a` appended..

Comment: sorry that was a typo...changed it..:)

Comment: To avoid both typos. as well as wasting the time of people who are offering help for free, ***always* copy/paste code, I/O, HTML/XML..**.

Comment: Ya well sometimes mistakes do happen...